# Can the Far Cry 3 minimap be set to be static (non-rotating)?

Tags: far-cry-3

I loathe rotating minimaps with a passion.

I really want to love FC3, but I just can't get over the rotating minimap. But I cannot find an ingame option to make the minimap stop rotating. You know, so it always points north and the character icon rotates within it.

I'd happily install a mod to do the job if someone could point me to one, assuming I'm not daft and missing an option in the menus someplace.

Comment: I hate that too in games. It makes the map obsolete, since you can often not tell which direction you are going as in North or East.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way. It might be moddable on PC but I'm not sure about that.